# Remote Desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I run a small network with around 50 remote clients using VPN to connect to Head office.

**VPN is built using no-ip.org as DNS.**

I am unable to RDP to one of remote client whereas the same client is able to RDP to my       workstation.

Kindly advise solution for above problem.

**Edit**

All my workstations are loaded with Windows7 professional and until a couple of days before I was able to RDP to that client.

Comment: A lot more information is required before people can assist you with this issue.  You need to provide versions of Windows involved, error messages, if any, what steps you are taking or have already tried to try and RDP, etc.

Comment: @Deb/Dave.. Thanks for your reply.. but all my workstations are loaded with Windows7 professional and untill a couple of days before i was able to RDP to that client, but now i dont know what went wrong also i checked everthing related to settings in Remote Tab.

Comment: I have turned off the firewall, Remote connection settings are set to accept remote connection.one more point i have 2 VPN connections and and the problem persists on both .

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what everyone else has already mentioned have you:

1. Basic connectivity checks, telnet from the source to the target, `telnet x.x.x.x 3389` and ping?
2. Does the user have admin access to his machine? If so are you certain they didn't install 3rd party internet security tools?
3. Have you verified RPC is running?
4. Remote Tab already mentioned
5. Certificates, if they're being used are you using the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

All of the windows version does not provide the facility of RDP.Xp sp1, Vista starter or Home basic,Home premium, Win7 home premium does not not have this feature means you can connect from this computer but another computer can't connect to your computer.
Only Windows XP sp3, vista professional, vista ultimate, Win7 Professional, Utimate provide these facility.

If you are sure that you have right version then check the settings My Computer-> Properties -> Remote tab and allow users to connect remotely.

Comment: I already mentioned the remote tab